# Why isn't my div showing?

Tags: php, html

Ignore the horrible code and formating, it's what I have to work with.

```
<div class="stories-pictures"><div class="inside">
        <?php for ($j=0; $j<2; $j++) foreach ($stories as $post) { /* can be empty field as well*/
            setup_postdata($post);
            if ($post->ID==$mainID && $j==0) {
                $link = get_permalink($productID);
                $title = "Back to <br/>".get_the_title($productID);
                $img = "<img class='backbg' width='316' height='234' src=".get_template_directory_uri()."/images/bg.png";
            } else if ($post->ID!=$mainID && $j==1) {
                $link = get_the_permalink()."?e=$productID";
                $title = get_the_title();
                $img = get_the_post_thumbnail(null,'story-thumb');
            } else continue;
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="storiespicture">
                <span>
                    <span><em>  <span class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></span></em></span>
                </span>
                <?php echo $img; ?>
                <div class="storieoverlay">
                </div> <!-- .storieoverlay -->
            </a>   <?php } ?>
        </div></div>
```

Here's what's outputted:

```
<a href="http://hidden/" class="storiespicture">
          <span>
            <span> <em> <span class="title" style="background-color: rgba(144, 137, 213, 0.901961);">hidden</span></em> </span>
          </span>
         <img width="316" height="234" src="http://hidden/hidden.jpg" class="attachment-story-thumb wp-post-image" alt="hidden">        </a>
```

I'm trying to get the `.storieoverlay` class to be under the `img`.

*I removed some possibly sensitive content, hence where hidden is shown.*

Comment: Your .storieoverlay div seems empty, maybe that's why it isn't showing ?
About putting it under the img, the divs are by default block level elements so they wont be displayed inline the image

Comment: im guessing the overlay is to prevent some kind of right click activity.  You would still see the html rendered.

Comment: When I say under the img, I don't mean under in the DOM, it should be on the same level as img, just under it.

Comment: I feel like there's some missing code above class="stories-pictures"

Comment: I dont see the `.inside` div in the output either. Are you sure there isnt further dom manipulation carried out (js) or that you are looking at the wrong code block? Use [view source] rather than [inspect element] to rule out the former

Comment: actually Pete below spotted the problem

Answer (score 2):

It's because you don't close your image tag:

```
 $img = "<img class='backbg' width='316' height='234' src=".get_template_directory_uri()."/images/bg.png";
```

Should be

```
 $img = "<img class='backbg' width='316' height='234' src='".get_template_directory_uri()."/images/bg.png'>";
```

Comment: note, to be xhtml compliant, it should probably end in `/>`

Comment: hahaha, @nomistic I added an answer yesterday that closed br tags in an xhtml manner and was told not to, today I don't bother and get told to!

Comment: This didn't work, or changing it to a span like stated below.

Comment: @DanielDewhurst, what does `get_the_post_thumbnail()` return? Also as I see you have closed your br tag, try closing the image tag with `/>` as nomistic suggested

Comment: @Pete I've tried closing the image tag off, that didn't work. Also, get_the_post_thumbnail() is a WordPress function that returns the URL of the thumbnail image associated to the post.

Comment: @DanielDewhurst What happens if you put the storieoverlay before the image?

Comment: @Pete You're a legend, that fixed it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool, but that would imply there may be a problem with the image tag

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue now.

It was a plugin outputting the mark up on this certain page, everything said here has been useful though, so thanks.